# Fork slider caps worn out. Replacements?

Tags: fork

I have this fork and the plastic slider sleeves have worn out. Can I purchase replacements. The service manual says those are among the "wear-and-tear" parts.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the brand and/or model of the fork in your post? That will help us find some information regarding parts. Most likely the manufacturer has parts for order if the fork is not too old.

Comment: The fork is SR SunTour, the exact model is not known but could be [SF7CR-8R](http://srsuntour-files.dbap.de/_public/tuningbase/downloadarea/catalogs/SRSuntour_Workshop_Book.pdf) (page 121).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to dig up a couple vendors providing replacements:

- [JEJames Cycles](http://www.jejamescycles.co.uk/sr-suntour-plastic-slider-sleeves-pair-id70444.html)
- [Fixed Gear Frenzy](http://www.fixedgearfrenzy.com/sr-suntour-plastic-slider-sleeves-for-bike.html)

And in case you're looking at doing this yourself:

- [SR Suntour: How to change slider sleeves](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cjadGqpfEo)

Answer (score 0):

The less expensive the fork, the less likely it is that you can find replacement parts for it. The glimmer of hope here is that you found a service manual and it lists part numbers along with noting that the parts in question are consumable. A call to your LBS, Suntour, or the bike manufacturer should sort this out. I would try them in that order.